# Module of the blender

Tags: python, scripting

I'm new about blender. And I was to run a script  and have a problem when run.
the code are like this:

```
import os 
import numpy as np
import bpy
from imp import reload
import morph_template as morph
from tools import blender_tools as blender
reload(blender)....
```

when I run it blender  it comes the ERROR:Import error : no module named "tools"
 (I used blender2.79, python3.6, Python IDE: Anaoconda it Installed nearly  all the common Python libs)
Would it be probably and module of blender of different version? If it is what version of blender of python should it be.If not which it might be? 
thanks a lot.

Comment: Where and what is the tools module?

Comment: that's the problem I'd like to know. I wonder if blender has the module named "tools", I used Blender 2.7. cause I'm quite new to this.